# Add new Row to Table and insert data from range

Tags: vba, range, row, new-operator

I have been asked to change data in a spreadsheet into a table.

Data needs to be pasted into this table from another workbook.

The code I have works fine whilst the data is in spreadsheet form but after being changed to a table I cannot get the code to add a new row or paste the data to that row.

This is the current code which works as long as the data is not in Table form.

```
Sub CopytoResults()

Dim destSht As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Copy the range 
ActiveSheet.Range("C52:AJ52").Select
Selection.Copy

'Open the Results spreadsheet and paste to the next available row
Workbooks.Open (ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Quality_ResultsTST.xlsx")
Set destSht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Staff Results")

destSht.Activate

'Paste Data
destSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

'Save and Close the Results Spreadsheet
destSht.Parent.Close True

'Set Focus to the QA_QC Assessment form
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Windows("QA Form V2.xlsm").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("E7").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

The Table name is Results

I've tried several solutions from this and other sites to no avail.

I know using select etc is bad form but this is not my code, I'm updating an old application.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a Table it would be something like this:

```
Sub CopytoResults()
    
    Dim rngSrc as range, wb as workbook
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'Copy the range 
    Set rngSrc = ActiveSheet.Range("C52:AJ52")
    
    set wb = Workbooks.Open(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Quality_ResultsTST.xlsx") 'ThisWorkbook?
    
    'add a new row to the table and assign the data to its Range
    with wb.sheets("Staff Results").listobjects("Results").listrows.add.range
        .value = rngSrc.value 
    end with

    wb.close true
    thisworkbook.Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("E7").Select
    
End Sub
```

Comment: That's great, thanks.  I can see where I went wrong not including the sheet name in the With statement.  Many Thanks.